# JPA WHERE clause

Tags: jpa

I am asking about WHERE clause. I have searched internet but I didn`t find answer for my question.

I have a few entity classes, which i represent below:

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "selectTrasy",
    query = "SELECT t FROM Trasa t WHERE t.raport = :raport ORDER BY t.id")
@Entity
public class Trasa  implements Serializable {
@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true )
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(name = "data_z")
private Date dataz;

@Column(name = "data_do")
private Date datado;

@Column(name = "czas_z")
private String czasZ;

@Column(name = "czas_do")
private String czasDo;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "miejscowosc_z")
private MiejscowoscDB miejscowoscZ;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "miejscowosc_do")
private MiejscowoscDB miejscowoscDo;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Uzytkownik user;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Raport raport;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return (other != null && getClass() == other.getClass() && id != null)
        ? id.equals(((Trasa) other).id)
        : (other == this);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (id != null) 
        ? (getClass().hashCode() + id.hashCode())
        : super.hashCode();
}

//next I have getters and setters
}


 @Entity
 public class Raport  implements Serializable {
@Id
@Column(name = "id", unique = true )
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(name = "data")
private Date data;

@Column(name = "nazwa")
private String nazwa;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Powod powod;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Uzytkownik uzytkownik;


@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return (other != null && getClass() == other.getClass() && id != null)
        ? id.equals(((Raport) other).id)
        : (other == this);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (id != null) 
        ? (getClass().hashCode() + id.hashCode())
        : super.hashCode();
}
 //getters and setters
 }
```

My question is why this query doesn`t work properly. Returned list is empty, but recordes exists in database, when I want return all Trasa records there is everything ok, only not works when I add WHERE clause with raport property.

```
trasy = (List<Trasa>)(manager.createNamedQuery("selectTrasy")
            .setParameter("raport", propertyWydatek.getRaport())
            .getResultList());
```

Comment: if there is no error, you are connecting to a other database or there are no records. switch the log level to debug an have a look at the generated sql queries.

Comment: I've noted that you use FetchType.LAZY in raport property on Trasa entity. Is there any possibility to propertyWydatek bring an non-fetched, empty, or null getRaport() call?

Comment: I have written that records exists in database and are returned without WHERE clause.

Comment: @Bonifacio raport coludn`t be non-fetched, empty or null, but property uzytkownik from raport is not fetched.

Comment: No uzytkownik is also fetched. There is no problem in this I think.

Comment: Do the query works without the WHERE clause?

Comment: select trasa0_.id as id1_2_, trasa0_.czas_do as czas_do2_2_, trasa0_.czas_z as czas_z3_2_, trasa0_.data_do as data_do4_2_, trasa0_.data_z as data_z5_2_, trasa0_.miejscowosc_do as miejscow6_2_, trasa0_.miejscowosc_z as miejscow7_2_, trasa0_.raport_id as raport_i8_2_, trasa0_.user_id as user_id9_2_ from Trasa trasa0_ where trasa0_.raport_id=? order by trasa0_.id

Comment: This is how looks SQL query, I don`t know why there is an empty field near by trasa_0.raport_id=?

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to:

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "selectTrasy",
    query = "SELECT t FROM Trasa t WHERE t.raport.id = :raportId ORDER BY t.id")
```

and run it like this:

```
trasy = (List<Trasa>)(manager.createNamedQuery("selectTrasy")
            .setParameter("raportId", propertyWydatek.getRaport().getId())
            .getResultList());
```

Other version of the query:

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "selectTrasy",
    query = "SELECT t FROM Trasa t join t.raport r WHERE r.id = :raportId ORDER BY t.id")
```

Comment: Yes. I knew this solution, but i thought that I can do it in other way

Comment: Still the same problem, in the debugger raport`s 'id' is for example 8 but in SQL is empty, why?

Comment: Is it empty or shown as `?`? You would need some more log settings to show the actual value that substitutes the `?`.

Comment: Use these log4j-settings: log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE (i assume you are using Hibernate..)

Comment: I`ve setted these settings but I still have the same log informations.